# Web Installer for IE browser helper objects?

Tags: internet-explorer, deployment, installation, windows-installer, bho

I have an extension for chrome and firefox, and now I want to port it to IE too. But I couldn't find a way to make the IE installer that doesn't involve the user downloading the file and then finding it and executing it (beside clicking run on the download dialog).

Is there a way to create a setup to be run from IE that just ask something like "do you want to install this extension?" then you click yes and it downloads and install the bho?

Update:

Just found an example of what I want to build: http://www.google.com/chrome
Once you click download and accept the terms the installer runs and just as "run or don't run", how could I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way -- I did this same thing several years ago (IE will still prompt the user). You create a thin ActiveX control that's packaged in a signed .cab file and referenced by an `<object ...>` tag on a web page. The ActiveX control after installation would download and launch the BHO installer. No mess and no fuss trying to find the BHO installer.

Comment: To sign a .cab do I need to buy some certificate or how is it done?

Comment: Google "Code Signing On The Cheap"

Answer (score 0):

For your update regarding Chrome: Chrome web installation uses [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) technology. Google's ClickOnce application installs the installer for Chrome which in turn does the download for the browser.